# Hourly Moving average over a duration

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to create a Moving average line based on hour for a selected duration. I want the x-axis to represent 24 hours of the day and the y-axis to represent the average value of each hour for the entire duration. For eg, I want the hourly average for the month of april of a person's effort.

I have written the following program but it prints the two days after the first. Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115000).

```
public class MovingAverageDemo extends ApplicationFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1570942379483983865L;

/**
 * A moving average demo.
 * @param title the frame title.
 */
public MovingAverageDemo(String title) {
    super(title);

    // create a title...
    String chartTitle = "Hourly Average";
    XYDataset dataset = createDataset();

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            chartTitle,
            "Hours",
            "Actions",
            dataset,
            true,
            true,
            false
    );

    LegendTitle legend = (LegendTitle) chart.getLegend();
    legend.setVisible(true);

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
    if(renderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
        StandardXYItemRenderer rr = (StandardXYItemRenderer) renderer;
        rr.setPlotLines(true);
        rr.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
    }

    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    XYItemLabelGenerator generator =
        new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator(
                StandardXYItemLabelGenerator.DEFAULT_ITEM_LABEL_FORMAT,
            format, format);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH"));
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);

}

/**
 * Creates a dataset, one series containing unit trust prices, the other a moving average.
 *
 * @return the dataset.
 */
public XYDataset createDataset() {

    TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("New", Hour.class);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 1)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 2)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 3)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 4)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 5)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 6)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 7)), 148);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 8)), 153);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 9)), 142);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 10)), 123);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 11)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 12)), 139);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 13)), 142);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 14)), 138);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 15)), 137);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 16)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 17)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 18)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 19)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 20)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 21)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 22)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 23)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 24)), 0);

    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 1)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 2)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 3)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 4)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 5)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 6)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 7)), 168);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 8)), 173);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 9)), 162);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 10)), 143);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 11)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 12)), 119);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 13)), 122);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 14)), 118);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 15)), 117);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 16)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 17)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 18)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 19)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 20)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 21)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 22)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 23)), 0);
    s1.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 24)), 0);

    TimeSeries s2 = MovingAverage.createMovingAverage(s1, "NewC", 1, 0);

    TimeSeries s3 = new TimeSeries("Cancelled", Hour.class);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 1)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 2)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 3)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 4)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 5)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 6)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 7)), 9);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 8)), 7);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 9)), 2);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 10)), 8);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 11)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 12)), 9);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 13)), 7);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 14)), 3);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 15)), 9);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 16)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 17)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 18)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 19)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 20)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 21)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 22)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 23)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, 24)), 0);

    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 1)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 2)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 3)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 4)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 5)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 6)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 7)), 9);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 8)), 7);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 9)), 2);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 10)), 8);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 11)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 12)), 9);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 13)), 7);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 14)), 3);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 15)), 9);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 16)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 17)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 18)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 19)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 20)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 21)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 22)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 23)), 0);
    s3.add(new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, 24)), 0);

    TimeSeries s4 = MovingAverage.createMovingAverage(s3, "CancelledC", 1, 0);

    TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    //dataset.addSeries(s1);
    dataset.addSeries(s2);
    //dataset.addSeries(s3);
    dataset.addSeries(s4);

    return dataset;
}

/**
 * Starting point for the demonstration application.
 *
 * @param args ignored.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MovingAverageDemo demo = new MovingAverageDemo("Moving Average Demo 1");
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);

}

private Date getDateByHour(int day, int month, int year, int hour) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    return cal.getTime();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem you're facing is? What behaviour you want / expect versus what you are getting. Also, what does this have to do with moving averages?

Comment: Actually, the 24 hour period is not added up and averaged properly. If you execute the above program you will get 48 points on the x-axis.

Comment: indeed, but you are adding points to your `TimeSeries` over a 48 hour period - `new Hour(getDateByHour(1, 4, 2012, hour))` and `new Hour(getDateByHour(2, 4, 2012, hour))` ...so what's the problem?

Comment: my requirement is to plot all data over 24 hour period. My sample adds all 24 hour data for 1st & 2nd May 2012.

Comment: If you want them over a 24 hour period, why are you adding them over a 48 hour period? As per my original comment, can you elaborate on what you want/expect and what you are getting. Break the problem down into the two halves - calcing the moving average or displaying the results... where is your problem?

Comment: lets forget the moving average as of now. I want to display the report for 1st & 2nd May on a 24 hour plot and I am getting 48 plots. Is there anyway to do this apart from manually handling the dataset so that it has only 24 plots.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your comments, you really want to display 4 series on your plot, not 2 - i.e.

- 01-May-2012 New
- 02-May-2012 New
- 01-May-2012 Cancelled
- 02-May-2012 Cancelled

You could then change your `getDateByHour()` method, or better yet, combine with the `new Hour(Date)` constructor called several times in `createDataset()`:

```
private Hour makeHour(int hour) {
  return new Hour(hour, 1, 1, 2012);
}
```

The actual day/month/year you use shouldn't matter, because you have set the `DateFormat` as "HH", so none of that gets rendered. (Providing you don't change the x-axis later...)

Comment: I want to display only 2 series New & Cancelled, each should be the average data per hour for both dates. So for a given duration I want to display average hourly data for each of these series.

Comment: @Atique - then you need to do the averaging before you put it into the `XYDataSet`. JFreeChart is for displaying data - not for doing calculations on the data.